# Intercom chat bot reply display again and again after dismissing it in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, intercom

I have Integrated intercom-react-native v3.0.5 in one of my react native apps. On sending a message, a default operator bot (not created custom bot) reply is received. Earlier it was displaying once if user dismisses it while using the app, but now I'm facing the issue that bot reply notification is appearing again and again even after

dismissing it. Facing this issue in ios only.

Thank you in advance for any help

[image: bot]

https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/2216447-custom-bots-explained

Is there any option to change settings for chat bot like a custom intercom bot

[image: Intercom]